Launch a Firefox Private Window using a Discrete Graphics Card
When right clicking on the Firefox (129.0.2) icon on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS there are several options to actually start the program:

Would it be possible to directly open a new private window using a discrete graphics card as in the first option (underlined in green in the image)?

Check the firefox.desktop file to see what the actual command lines for these actions are, then combine them suitably

This mozilla support post might be helpful in answering your question. #
